# Firebase Backward compatibility with GCM

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a project that uses push notifications via a 3rd party service that uses GCM under the hood.

I have access to the device tokens, but I see no way to import those to the Firebase Cloud Messaging. I know that for iOS, there is a way to import APNs tokens, but I can't find a way to do that for Android.

Is there a way to send push notifications to GCM registered tokens or to import them to Firebase?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the problem, GCM and FCM are the same under the hood. A Token for GCM work for FCM as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreeing with @TimCasteljins, the post is a bit unclear, specifically where you want to *import the registration tokens to FCM*.

However, if you are referring to use them in FCM, there is no need to *import* them. As what was also mentioned by Tim Casteljins in the comments, you may still send push notifications to those tokens using FCM. So long as you use the corresponding Sender ID and Server Key.

If you are planning to use FCM, why not just [Migrate to FCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) completely?

Comment: That is what I was looking for. I was misled by the fact that iOS has some token import mechanism but android doesn't. Making them compatible looks like the right and easy way to do it. Thank you for pointing it out.