# Migrating from GCM to latest FCM but get the same Token

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I used to upgrade my other APP from GCM to FCM, and when the user already installed the App on their device, the first time they open after migration, I assumed they get FCM token that is different from the original GCM token (Sorry I'm not very sure, it's a long time ago). In that App, the FCM version is 11.8.0.

And now in my current migrating App, I'm migrating from GCM to the latest FCM version which is 17.3.4. When I tried to just copy and paste my code, I found out I need to make some arrangements along the way. So I followed:
[FirebaseInstanceIdService is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51123913/3405938) and [Firebase (FCM) how to get token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41515597/3405938).

But now the tester in our company told me the new FCM token I send to the server is the same as the old GCM token. Just wondering if this is normal or not, I don't see anyone asking the same question and just trying to make sure I didn't miss anything or do something wrong, thanks in advance.

Comment: just check if you ara able to receive the push messages, and if you are able - then it's all fine

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I can when I used FCM console, but the server side is going to push notification to customers in bulk. And it can't switch to FCM due to company restrictions right now. So we have to make sure everything will work fine after server side makes the change.

Comment: I think if you were able to do with FCM console, that it should work fine with a server too.

Comment: That what I think, too. But the people above want a concrete answer because Chinese New year is near, we need to make sure this function work. But thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A registration token is ["*implicitly linked to the package name of the app + device where it was generated*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11587181/4625829) -- so it is plausible that the device returns the same token if it is for the same app and the same project. Even though the answer is quite old (GCM days), I believe that this behavior still stands. This makes sense because [the backwards compatibility for GCM and FCM is still active](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43017737/4625829) ([similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39961156/4625829)).

Comment: Thank you for answering. Have a nice day!